# Multiple parameters in single variable

Tags: powershell

Attempting to use few variables that contain multiple parameter values.

```
$iniFileContent["Settings"].GetEnumerator() | Select -ExpandProperty value | ForEach-Object {
    Convert-WindowsImage -SourcePath $iniFileContent.Locations.ServerISO $_
}
```

Script looks into my .ini file:

```
[Settings]
CreateVM1=-VHDFormat "VHDX" -Edition "ServerStandardEval"
CreateVM2=-VHDFormat "VHDX" -Edition "ServerStandardEval"

[Locations]
ServerISO=C:\server2012.iso
```

End result should be:

```
Convert-WindowsImage -SourcePath $iniFileContent.Locations.ServerISO -VHDFormat "VHDX" -Edition "ServerStandardEval"
```

The error is **"A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument [...]".** From my understanding, the problem occurs because the variable `$_` contains multiple parameter values, which it attempts to use as a single parameter.

What's the correct way to parse a string with multiple parameter values to a function?

Comment: what does `$iniFileContent["Settings"].GetEnumerator() | Select -ExpandProperty value` show?... that is what `$_` is

Comment: -VHDFormat "VHDX" -Edition "ServerStandardEval"

Comment: Can you maybe show us the code that populates the `$iniFileContent` variable from the ini file in the first place?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Invoke-Expression` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-3.0):

> Syntax
>
> ```
> Invoke-Expression [-Command] <String> [<CommonParameters>]
> ```
>
> Description
>
> The `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet evaluates or runs a specified string as
>   a command and returns the results of the expression or command.
>   Without `Invoke-Expression`, a string submitted at the command line
>   would be returned (echoed) unchanged.

I use `iex` alias instead of full `Invoke-Expression` merely for better readability:

```
$iniFileContent["Settings"].GetEnumerator() | 
  Select -ExpandProperty value | ForEach-Object {
    iex $("Convert-WindowsImage -SourcePath $($iniFileContent.Locations.ServerISO) " + $_)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!